# background-color passing through position: absolute pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm designing a :hover sliding button animation but for some reason when the button is hovered I can still see the color from the element under it passing through on the bottom and top left corners as you can see it on the second picture, its not much but scaled down it displays a colored pixel on the screen, I don't even know how to describe it in english to search for solutions on google (english isn't my native language). It seems to be a weird interaction between `overflow: hidden` and `border-radius`. thanks in advance.

ps: maybe gradient is the way to go ?

Here is the html/css code:

```
<div class="header-buttons">
    <a class="btn" href="#"><span>Contactez-nous</span></a>
</div>
```

```
.header-buttons {
    grid-area: btn;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    .btn {
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        padding: 1rem 1.6rem;
        background-color: inherit;
        color: inherit;
        border-radius: 2px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        font-weight: 500;
        display: block;
        span {
            z-index: 2;
            position: relative;
        }
        &::before {
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: $gris-clair;
            transform: translatex(-102%);
            transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;

        }
        &:hover {
            color: $font;
            &::before {
                transform: translatex(-3%);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: button default]

[image: button hovered]

Comment: You seem to be on the right path maybe that idea you have that on hove has a gradient at the end to avoid the corner issue, which seems to be an old issue that never got addressed by browsers

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to solve those corners. Here's a codepen if someone want's to play around: https://codepen.io/cisco_iz/pen/eYggzVW?editors=1100
I think this is known as the subpixel problem. More info on that here: https://johnresig.com/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/